# Access denied when accessing mysql database

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I have attempted to install a mysql powered dating app known as Youdate (https://youdate.website/demo) on my test server after setting up an empty database. I added an admin account using the MySql wizard on my server's cpanel. However, when I try to access the database through SSH I am presented with the following error:

`mysql -u testadmin -p ****`

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I have changed the password using the cpanel and phpmyadmin to no avail.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: `-p ****` for password is not valid. There should be no space(s) between `-p` and your password value so it should be `-pyourpassword`

Comment: Your problem is the password, as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

you should check your table form mysql.user for user testadmin;
Do you have permission to log in to localhost? It is recommended to use the ip address, or' testadmin'@'%', so that this user can log in at any other ip address. At the same time, check whether this user has any permission to database.